# Adding CDATA to XML fields

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

How to add CDATA to all generated fields in python from xlsx to xml?

Code looks like:

```
from lxml import etree as et

raw_data = pd.read_excel(r'path_to_file')
root = et.Element('document')


for row in raw_data.iterrows():
    root_tags = et.SubElement(root, 'root')  
    # These are the tag names for each row 
    Column_heading_1 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'sku')
    Column_heading_2 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'product_url')

    # The values inside the [] are the raw file column headings.
    Column_heading_1.text = str(row[1]['sku'])
    Column_heading_2.text = str(row[1]['product_url'])

tree = et.ElementTree(root)
et.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)
tree.write('output.xml', encoding="utf-8")
```

and in output I need:

```
<document>
            <root>
                <sku><![CDATA[Z.18181.16158141231205807]]></sku>
                <product_url><![CDATA[https://link.test]]></product_url>
            </root>
            <root>
                <sku><![CDATA[Z.18181.16158141231205807]]></sku>
                <product_url><![CDATA[https://link.test]]></product_url>
            </root>
</document>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.CDATA-class.html?

Comment: Seems like a waste to add CDATA to something as simple as "Z.18181.16158141231205807". All that does is make the XML file larger.

Comment: @Tomalak my data look like this:
أرواب مودرن - ليموني

Comment: I want to import it by XLSTX and somewhere in data can be symbols, that I want to escape :) (like &nbsp;)
@mzjn thanks for advice, just CDATA(str(row[1]['sku'])) and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add [`CDATA`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.CDATA-class.html), e.g.:

```
Column_heading_1.text = et.CDATA(str(row[1]['sku']))
```